# ARM Cortex-M7 GCC Linker error Relocation truncated to fit R_ARM_PREL31 when trying to place some files in another memory section

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, ld, cortex-m

Good day everyone.

I have a large project for STM32H747XI and there is many of code files that could not be placed into main FLASH memory region so I'm trying to place it on external QSPI flash. So I created additional .qtext session for these files and placed it above main .text section.

```
 .qtext :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    ioquake3/* (.text)          /* .text sections (code) */
    ioquake3/* (.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    _eqtext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >QSPI
```

Original .text section which placed below also there.

```
.text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH
```

But when I'm trying to compile it Linker throws me set of errors.

```
12:48:31 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project ioquake3test_CM7 ****
make all 
arm-none-eabi-g++ -o "ioquake3test_CM7.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m7 -T"E:\STM32CubeIDE\ioquake3test\CM7\STM32H747XIHX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="ioquake3test_CM7.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static -u_printf_float --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -Wl,--end-group
ioquake3/swGL/CommandDrawTriangle.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EE10_M_releaseEv[_ZNSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EE10_M_releaseEv]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EE10_M_releaseEv'
ioquake3/swGL/CommandDrawTriangle.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EED2Ev[_ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EED5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EED2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt15_Rb_tree_headerC2Ev[_ZNSt15_Rb_tree_headerC5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt15_Rb_tree_headerC2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt15_Rb_tree_header8_M_resetEv[_ZNSt15_Rb_tree_header8_M_resetEv]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt15_Rb_tree_header8_M_resetEv'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EE13_Rb_tree_implISA_Lb1EEC2Ev[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EE13_Rb_tree_implISA_Lb1EEC5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EE13_Rb_tree_implISA_Lb1EEC2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EE13_Rb_tree_implISA_Lb1EED2Ev[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EE13_Rb_tree_implISA_Lb1EED5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EE13_Rb_tree_implISA_Lb1EED2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EEC2Ev[_ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EEC5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIiSt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEESt10_Select1stIS6_ESt4lessIiESaIS6_EEC2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt3mapIiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEESt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiS3_EEEC2Ev[_ZNSt3mapIiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEESt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiS3_EEEC5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt3mapIiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEESt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiS3_EEEC2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt12__shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EED2Ev[_ZNSt12__shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EED5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt12__shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE0EED2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEED2Ev[_ZNSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEED5Ev]+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_PREL31 against `.text._ZNSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEED2Ev'
ioquake3/swGL/Context.o:(.ARM.exidx.text._ZNSaISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEEEEC2Ev[_ZNSaISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKiSt10shared_ptrIN4SWGL7ContextEEEEEC5Ev]+0x0): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:122: ioquake3test_CM7.elf] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

12:48:40 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 9s.177ms)
```

I also have more sections for .qrodata, .qdata and .qbss for same purpose but it throws me an errors only when I'm trying to create separated .qtext section.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're branching too far away. IIRC, you can branch with bl for 24-bit distances. Looking at the reference manual of the specified chip on pages 135 and 136 the memory is specified. I found the following data:

- On-board flash ranges from 0x08000000 to 0x081FFFFF
- Memory mapped QSPI ranges from 0x90000000 to 0x9FFFFFFF

That distance is > 24-bits. Adding -fPIC could solve this.